# Same query, different results

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, mariadb

I'm running a cron daily, and keep records saved in a table. Wrote a query to see the daily progress of the users, but facing an issue.
I have local and production environments with separate data bases.

```
SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER(PARTITION BY node_id ORDER BY created_at) old_value
FROM ledger WHERE ledger_type_id = 1
```

This is the part of the query that is failing. I think the db driver has something to do it. The query was working on the prod data base, from my SQL client, but I just noticed that it is running MySQL 8, and the prod db is 10.3.16-MariaDB.
Tried the same query on my local data base - MySQL 5.7, and got this error:

```
[2019-08-06 16:12:47] [42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
 to use near '(PARTITION BY node_id ORDER BY created_at) AS old_value
```

After this I did 2 more tests:

1. Ran the query on the prod server it self, via phpmyadmin, and the server complete died, for a few minutes.
2. Ran the query from my code on the prod environment (laravel 5.8):

```
DB::select(DB::raw('
    SELECT *, LAG(value) OVER(
    PARTITION BY node_id ORDER BY created_at
    ) old_value
    FROM ledger WHERE ledger_type_id = 1
'))
```

and got this in my laravel log:

```
production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is
illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause
```

Am I doing something incorrect?

Comment: MySQL only started supporting lag with version 8.  You are probably using an older version.

Comment: 'MariaDB starting with 10.2.2
The LAG() function was first introduced with other window functions in MariaDB 10.2.' https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/lag/ - MYSQL and MARIADB  are sufficiently forked for me to be wary of combining the 2 without keeping a close eye on compatibility.